# Android get pictures from gallery and give user the option to launch camera

Tags: android, camera, gallery

I know how to launch camera and let user take a picture; I also know how to launch gallery and let user pick one of the pictures on the device; however, on the gallery launching page, the only option to user is "cancel".
I want to give user more options on that page such as, opening camera,crop, delete, etc. just like how native gallery works. Do I need to use putExtra()? If I do, how to find out what I can use with it.

I understand an option is to have a page/dialog to let user choose between two options, but it does not look so stunning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that point you will be messing with the receiving intent's activity. Unless it gives you that ability (I don't know of one that does), you can't do it.  You have to return the image to your own activity and display a menu there.

Keep in mind that a user can have any number of galleries installed, and the user might not be looking at the image in the stock gallery app depending on their personal settings/preference.

What if you created an activity that displayed the image, then had a simple listview alertdialog show with some options?  That might look clean enough.

Comment: You are right. I think thats what I am going to do, I spent two hours researching on this, looks like its not an option.